# "Joined today ago"

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, dates

In the new Accounts tab, a user can have joined "today ago".

> [image]

Comment: Well, the user mayan arrivan on-when.

Comment: Are you referring to "member for"?

Comment: @Arjan No he's referring to the text `Joined today ago` below. Just Ctrl+F it, if you can't find it.

Comment: See: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14571816/thisthing.png

Comment: Your unicorn is missing its horn.

Comment: @Nicholas, Yi: Thanks for the screenshot and unicorn.

Comment: @Gabe: Unicorn horniness has been resolved, but the edit will need to be approved.

Comment: And here I am, thinking that unicorns exist only in legends... :-D

Comment: Should it be todayS?

Comment: I think this problem will solve itself tomorrow...

Comment: @Ivo - you mean "joined yesterday ago"???

Comment: Please use the correct spelling "too days ago"

Comment: +1 for epic Hitchhiker's Guide reference, @Nicholas.  Also, I'm not clear what the proposed solution would be. Should it say: "Joined to dayago?" or "Joined to daya go"?

Comment: Some other suggested fixes "joined al qaed ago", "joined fandan ago", or "you can check out any time you like, but you can never leave."

Comment: When I first join `http://gaming.stackexchange.com/` my "member for" went funky too and showed minus (-10 seconds I think) for couple of hours. As it can't really be reproduced I didn't submit bug report..

Comment: @Shadow: That's understandable if the servers aren't completely synched. There's a question about negative times on answers here somewhere.

Comment: @Tim thanks! By the way, if you want rep boost, add "Eeeek!" to the title somehow. :P

Comment: Don't have the 15rep on meta to upvote, but +1 in the comments!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is fixed now ago. Sorry about that — I didn't test exhaustively enough.

Comment: Cool, thanks!  P.S. My comments were not mocking you, just making light of the situation. We should all laugh at silly little bugs because we all make them.

Answer (score 9):

This problem resolves itself after 24 hours (at the latest). Please be patient for the server caching to catch up. After that time, "today ago" will become "yesterday ago" and eventually "2 days ago" (alternatively, "todays ago" according to [reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)).

Comment: Come on, this is still lame. It's a polish thing, but I'd expect that from a otherwise so great platform as SO.

Comment: Agreed. Nothing is perfect, though. I think we've all been here, though. As much as we'd like to think we're the "bestest programmers that ever lived", we all have this kind of thing happen to us.  I'm not mocking the SO developers as much as making light of an embarrassing situation we've all had to go through.