# Yesterday? Wow... Did I go back in time?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, answers

I just looked at my question from [**two days ago**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115168/155556) and it says I asked it **yesterday**:

[image: yesterday?]

Here is what I get when I hover over the **yesterday** next to my name:

> 2011-12-07 17:14:10Z

And Popular Demand:

> 2011-12-07 18:56:27Z

What is going on here?

Just to give some perspective for future readers the time on this question says:

> 2011-12-09 15:08:52Z

I think it is linked to this issue: [Why when the bounty is over do I not see how long I have to select an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115319/155556)

Comment: Hmm... do I downvote this because I've already read 231,908 SE date format questions, or follow my "it mentions my name (in a non-insulting manner) so it gets an upvote" policy?

Comment: @PopularDemand :-) any examples of other date format issues?

Comment: @Popular You have a "it mentions my name so it gets an upvote" policy? *Makes note to use Popular Demand as a demonstration user in all future bug reports/feature requests/discussions*

Comment: Oh, hey, look at that. +1 @John.

Comment: ["Joined today ago"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84854) and [Slightly wrong "member for" date in profile for unregistered user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75087) and [Why are the dates on timestamps and such not showing the year?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41500) (and the _five_ posts in its comment) and [Timesensitive: Calculation of Yesterday is off](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101694) and [Times before 10 am should show leading 0 for hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110577) and (continued next comment)

Comment: (continued from previous comment) [Member for 12 months?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109043) and [Use "just now" and "momentarily" appropriately, please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107486) and [Comments showing "momentarily" instead of "just now" again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107358) and [Momentarily in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106410) and ["You can accept an answer just now"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106067) and [openid.stackexchange.com still uses "in 0 seconds" instead of "just now"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106018); shall I go on?

Comment: @PopularDemand Ahh! ok. got it :-P

Answer (score 18):

It was more than 24 and less than 48 hours ago....

Comment: That is still **not** yesterday.... It is two dates away! It should have better wording if that is the case....

Comment: It hasn't been two days yet. Why should it say "two days ago"?

Comment: @mmyers It should **not** say yesterday though.... because it is older than yesterday....

Comment: @ama: It depends on your time zone if it really is older than yesterday. But maybe "1 day ago" would be more accurate.

Comment: @sth maybe, idk. but if the 24-48 hour thing is the case, then it definitely needs better wording....

Comment: This is the base porblem with saying "yesterday" when the system is based on "hours ago"; it will not line up with the intuitive, arguably cannot-be-more-correct definition of "the previous date".

Comment: @Toomai I guess. but when the system sees that the dayes are **2 date values** apart, it should know that it was **not** yesterday....

Comment: It apparently doesn't look at the date values though; that's the porblem.

Comment: @Toomai That is an issue.... :-\

Comment: @sth - Aren't "1 day ago" and "yesterday" synonymous?

Comment: @kevin: I feel like "One day ago" emphasizes the time span that has passed while "yesterday" emphasizes that a new day started. But that might be just my personal impression.

Comment: "Yesterday", as used in everyday language, implies that since the event there's been a midnight.