# Burninate the stackoverflow.com tag?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags

In looking at [the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com), they pretty much all seem to belong on Meta.  Can anybody think of a purpose served by this tag that's on-topic for SO?

Maybe if someone attempts to use it they can be notified that:

> Hey, if you're asking a question *about* StackOverflow, why not hop over to http://meta.stackoverflow.com and join the discussions there?

New users are unlikely to even know about Meta, but this might help them along.

(That's more just thinking aloud, the actual request here is to nuke the tag.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why thank you for providing us with a nice list of questions to close and vote to migrate to MSO! :-D

On a more serious note, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411740/stack-overflow-reputation-api) does seem like it *might* be on-topic for Stack Overflow, as it's asking how to actually programmatically interface with stackoverflow.com.

[Here's a much better example by high-rep Meta user Popular Demand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6986461/75801). He knows what he's doing, that *is* an on-topic Stack Overflow [stackoverflow.com](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com) question.

I think you're correct about <strike>almost all of</strike> many of the others, they belong here instead. As I review the list I do find a number that are saying "How do I do *x* **like Stack Overflow does**, and those are clearly on-topic for SO, and *off-* topic for MSO.

WIth the recent flood of questions on MSO which are *totally* off topic, I don't think we should ban this tag and direct people here, however. That would be counterproductive

Comment: That one's kind of borderline, I agree.  I think the difference comes down to "How do I interface with SO?" (Meta) vs. "Here's how I'm trying to interface with a service (which happens to be SO!), and here's a problem I'm having." (SO)

Comment: Been [following Bob Cratchit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115465/yesterday-wow-did-i-go-back-in-time#comment-300892), have you?

Comment: But then, shouldn't they be migrated to Stackapps.SE?