# Shouldn't the stackoverflow.com tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Burninate the stackoverflow.com tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116120/burninate-the-stackoverflow-com-tag)

Uh, why does this tag exist on StackOverflow?

[stackoverflow.com](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com)

Comment: How would the site know about itself? Have some pity!

Comment: @Oded: Good question.  Maybe we should have some kind of related site, where we can talk about the site?  Somebody should blog about that!

Comment: 200 question tagged with it? Oh dear...

Comment: @SimonSheehan - a lot will be migration stubs that point back to here and will get deleted, but not all.

Comment: Good to see even *you* ask duplicate questions sometimes :)

Comment: @ChrisF, unfortunately [151 of the 206](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[stackoverflow.com]+closed%3A0) questions are still open.

Comment: @Won't I think we should start a site-about-the-site meme!